# Qt unexpected EOF while looking for matching

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, qt

I tried to run the project from 
https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse576/14wi/Assignment1.htm
on
OS X 10.9.5 | Xcode 2 6.1 | Qt Creator 3.2.2(opensource) Based on Qt 5.3.2

But got the following error

```
> /Users/MyName/Qt/5.3/clang_64/bin/qmake -spec macx-clang CONFIG+=debug
> CONFIG+=x86_64 -o Makefile ../code/ImageStitcher.pro
> /Applications/Xcode
> 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
> -c -pipe -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk
> -mFile Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /Applications/Xcode Invalid Arguments  -version-min=10.6 -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB
> -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -I../code -I../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode -I2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers
> -I/Applications/Xcode -I2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers/
> -I. -I. -F/Users/MyName/Qt/5.3/clang_64/lib -o main.o ../code/main.cpp /bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
> /bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file make: ***
> [main.o] Error 2 22:13:50: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with
> code 2. Error while building/deploying project ImageStitcher (kit:
> Desktop Qt 5.3 clang 64bit) When executing step "Make"
```

I have changed

```
!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.9
qdevice.pri
```

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the exact same problem.  It seems that my auto-generated Makefile is corrupt.  This could be a qmake bug.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by removing the whitespace in `/Applications/Xcode 2.app`.  The tricky part is forcing qmake to realize the change.

Solution:

1. Rename your "Xcode N.app" to something without spaces (I deleted my older Xcode installation and renamed my "Xcode N.app" to `/Applications/Xcode.app`)
2. Run `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app` (or whatever else you named it).
3. Delete the file named `.qmake.stash` in your build directory.  My project was located in `~/test/` and my build directory was `~/build-test-Desktop_Qt_5_3_clang_64bit-Debug/`, so I ran `rm -f ~/build-test-Desktop_Qt_5_3_clang_64bit-Debug/.qmake.stash` to delete the file.
4. Build.  It should work now.

Comment: @willsapgreen: Have you had a chance to try this yet?